# Finiteness condition

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading an [article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176996268) from the field of probabilities and I have a problem understanding a basic analysis condition.

If we have an **unbounded** function $f(x)$ then what is the meaning of the condition $M_r(f)<\infty$ for some $r$ where
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
M_r(f)=\sup_x(1+|x|^r)^{-1}|f(x)|, \ \ r>0\\
M_r(f)=\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|:x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}, \ \ r=0.\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Will this condition ($M_r(f)<\infty$) be satisfied for the function $f(x)=e^x$, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_r(f) < \infty$ is a growth condition.

- For $r > 0$ it means that $|f|$ is not growing faster than the polynomial $1 + |x|^r$: If $M_r(f) = C < \infty$ then for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$ there holds $$(1+|x|^r)^{-1} |f(x)| \leq M_r(f) = C \;\Longrightarrow\; |f(x)| \leq C (1+|x|^r).$$
- For $r = 0$ it is equivalent to $|f|$ being bounded, i.e. $|f|$ not growing faster than a constant polynomial: If $M_0(f) = C < \infty$ then $|f(x)| \leq |f(0)| + |f(x)-f(0)| \leq |f(0)| + C$, i.e. $|f|$ is bounded. Conversely, if $|f(x)| < M$ we have that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq 2 M$, i.e. $M_0(f) \leq 2M$.

Because $f(x) = e^x$ is growing faster than any polynomial the condition $M_r(f) < \infty$ is not satisfied for any $r$.